# How to combine multi Single in one

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I am developing an Android app using Firebase Firestore (Remote database) and Room(Sqlite, local database).

In this app, at the first time, get data from the Firebase server and insert them into the local database.

There are multiple tables, so I should call it multiple times for every table.

for example,

- monster table
- item table
- skill table
- weapon table
- ...

and here are firebase functions:

```
class MonsterDataSource(val mMonsterDao: MonsterDao) {

    private val TAG = MonsterDataSource::class.java.simpleName

    fun sync(): Single<Boolean> {
        return Single.create<Boolean> { emitter ->
            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(MONSTERS)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                        // Get data from the firebase
                        val monsters = mutableListOf<Monster>()
                        it.result.documents.forEach {
                            monsters.add(it.toObject(Monster::class.java)!!)
                        }

                        // insert data into the local database
                        Observable.fromCallable {
                            mMonsterDao.save(*monsters.toTypedArray()) }
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe {
                                Log.d(TAG, "[MHW][Monster] save done")
                                emitter.onSuccess(true)
                            }
                    } else {
                        emitter.onError(FirestoreGetFailureException())
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

- ItemDataSource
- SkillDataSource
- WeaponDataSource
- ...

I don't know how to combines these singles into one.

```
fun syncData() {
    val monsterSingle = MonsterDataSource().sync()
    val itemSingle = ItemDataSource().sync()
    val skillSingle = SkillDataSource().sync()
    val weaponSingle = WeaponDataSource().sync()
    ...

    // I want to know when all data are stored in the local database.
}
```

At the first time, the app is locked to get the data from the server.
After all data sync done(get from firebase, insert in local database), I want to unlock the app.
But I don't know how can I combine the multiple Singles and get the "onComplete" method.

Or

If you have other solution, it will be helpful for me.

Comment: Why are you adding data also in the Sqlite since Firestore has offline persistens enabled by default?

Comment: @AlexMamo I want to use a flexible query like Join. In case of the Firestore, I think it is not easy... it will be callback hell...

Comment: There is a workaround in NoSql databases to achieve the same thing. Why to use and mantain two databases since Firestore already provides a locat database that can even work when offline. If you'll add another question regarding this topic, me or other users might help you with that.

Comment: hmm... Sorry, I thought wrong. I will find the way to query it in the Firestore. Actually, it may the best solution.

Comment: Yes, that's correct what Frank said but only if you intend to use it as a primary local offline database. But in your actual question you are using Cloud Firestore, why not using Sqlite it at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can flatMap each of them.

for example

```
new MonsterDataSource().sync()
    .flatMap(monsterSingleResult -> ItemDataSource().sync())
    .flatMap(itemSingleResult -> SkillDataSource().sync())
    // more flatMaps
    .subscribe(finalResult -> {
        // done with all the jobs
     });
```

Another option is to `zip` them together

```
Single.zip(monsterSingle,itemSingle,...,(monsterResult,itemResult,...) -> {
    // final result
})
```

They will be executed sequentially unless you use `Scheduler`.